# android textview with progress bar vertical alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am newbie to android programming. I am trying to make a webview application. Now while loading a url, I am showing texview and a progressbar.

How do I align progressbar and text view in the center of screen ?

Following is my code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prog_bar"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what kind of center?? horizontal center?? vertical ccenter, or bullseye center?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your text and progress to be displayed on top of the WebView in the center of the screen, then I suggest to use Relativelayout instead LinearLyaout e.g.

ProgressBar is centered in both orientations and text is placed below progress and horizontally centered in the parent.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/prog_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sample text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prog_bar"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `wrap_content` in your `WebView` width and height if you want the **widgets** to be located in the center of the screen.

**sample:**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If you dont use `wrap_content` then it will fill the screen making the widgets aligned at the top of the scree but horizontally centered.